# c# Log In click event using authentication against Active Directory through LDAP

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, active-directory

I am quite new to c# and LDAP, I'm doing this project so that I could learn about them in a more hands on approach.

What I'm trying to create is a Log in form that has a log in click event that would authenticate the username and password after the user enters them through the active directory using LDAP.

I have read [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) to be able to understand this subject better and I have also gone through similar topics here this one dealing with the validation in itself ([c# - Validate a username and password against Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory)) and this one authenticating a username ([c# against Active Directory over LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469588/c-sharp-against-active-directory-over-ldap))

From the first linked topic I had learned that the following code should do the trick in authenticating a username and password:

```
  using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://example.string.com/OU=Users, Dc=example, Dc= string, DC=com"))
        {
            bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(User, Password);
        }
```

So my approach to incorporate this to a click event was as follows:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://example.string.com/OU=Users, Dc=example, Dc= string, DC=com"))

            bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(User, Password);

             if(isValid)
             {
                 Main m = new Main();
                 this.Close();
                 m.Show();
             }
             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username and/or Password","Error!");
                 textBox1.Clear();
                 textBox2.Clear();
                 textBox1.Focus();

             }
```

Which is giving me a bool error of Embedded Statement.
I tried the other approach I had read from the second post which was to use this code which authenticates only Username:

```
         PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://example.com/OU=Computers,OU=Users,dc=example,dc=com");

        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "username");


        bool userExists = (user != null);
```

But I found that I wont be able to authenticate a password using this method as **UserPrincipal.FindByPassword** does not exist.

I have also tried it this way but again **.Password** does not exist:

```
 PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"LDAP://....");

        UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(pc);
        qbeUser.EmployeeId = User;

        //.Password does not exist
        UserPrincipal qbePassword = new UserPrincipal(pc);
        qbePassword.Password = Password;

        // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
        PrincipalSearcher srchUser = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);
         PrincipalSearcher srchPass = new PrincipalSearcher(qbePassword);
        // try to find that user and password
        UserPrincipal founduser = srchUser.FindOne() as UserPrincipal;
        UserPrincipal foundpass = srchPass.FindOne() as UserPrincipal;

        if (founduser != null)
        {
            if (foundpass != null)
            {
                Main m = new Main();
                this.Close();
                m.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password Not Valid.");
                textBox2.Clear();
                textBox2.Focus();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username Not Valid.");
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
```

Can someone kindly please instruct me as how one should correctly approach this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "Which is giving me a bool error of Embedded Statement" below your first solution? In general that approach should work, maybe your problem isn't the authentication in general.

Comment: Yes, there was a minor syntax error in my first approach, that's causing the bool error. I've already corrected it and will test it now and see if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this but not with PrincipalContext. Instead I have found many people struggling using that object.

My implemenatation was a winforms form and the submit button calls a method executing the 4 las lines of the code below.

I tested against this magnificent [free to test LDAP server](https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/#comment-6953)

```
var path = "LDAP://ldap.forumsys.com:389/dc=example,dc=com";
var user = $@"uid={username},dc=example,dc=com";
var pass = "password";

var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path, user, pass, AuthenticationTypes.None);

var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("*");
var searchResult = searcher.FindOne();
```

I don´t understand exactly what all of this lines does.

**Important tips**

On the path the "LDAP://" string should be on block mayus.

In the user, according to the  test server you use "cn=username-admin" for validating admins, be sure to also set Authentication type to ServerBind.